# NSNotificationCenter and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone

I hope to get the http header info(file size) in asynchronous mode.

So I initialize as codes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(processReadResponseHeaders:) name:@"readResponseHeaders"
                                           object:nil];
```

my codes to read the http header

```
-(void)processReadResponseHeaders: (ASIHTTPRequest *)request ;//(id)sender;
{


    unsigned long long contentLength = [request contentLength]; //error occurs here

}
```

It has to change the source code of ASIHTTPRequest.m

I did add my codes in function readResponseHeaders to notify the event is triggered )

```
- (void)readResponseHeaders
{
     //.........................
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"readResponseHeaders"  object:self];//

}
```

the log file reports:

2010-05-15 13:47:38.034 myapp[2187:6a63] *** -[NSConcreteNotification contentLength]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x46e5bb0

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter's observers' selector *must* have one of the signatures:

```
-(void)observe;
-(void)observeWithNotification:(NSNotification*)notification;
```

It cannot be an ASIHTTPRequest (even if you put `ASIHTTPRequest*` in the argument, it is still an NSNotification.)

There are 3 properties of NSNotification: `name`, `object` and `userInfo`. You could obtain the  ASIHTTPRequest with `object`, if `self` is an ASIHTTPRequest when you post that notification:

```
-(void)processReadResponseHeaders:(NSNotification*)notification {
    ASIHTTPRequest* request = [notification object];
    unsigned long long contentLength = [request contentLength];
    ...
}
```